# Adding variables to a dictionary Swift

Tags: swift

I would like to define a constant string variable as a variable in class.(More precisely for both key and value).

The example I'm working on is as follows.This code is in a class called JsonHandler.

```
enum JsonTcpStatus: Int {
    case JSON_GET = 4
}

let JSON_NAME_METHOD = "A"


let getJSON: String = {
    do {
        let temp_dic = [JSON_NAME_METHOD: JsonTcpStatus.JSON_GET.rawValue]
        let jsonData = try JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: temp_dic, options: [])
        let str = String(data: jsonData, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8)! + "\r"
        return str
    } catch let error as NSError {
        print(error)
    }
    return ""
}()
```

This code does not work and gives error: "Instance member 'JSON_NAME_METHOD' cannot be used on type 'JsonHandler'"

I get the same error in the code below.

```
enum JsonTcpStatus: Int {
    case JSON_GET = 4
}

let JSON_NAME_METHOD = "A"

let getJSON: String = {
    do {
        var temp_dic = [String: Any]()
        temp_dic[JSON_NAME_METHOD] = JsonTcpStatus.JSON_GET.rawValue
        let jsonData = try JSONSerialization.data(withJSONObject: temp_dic, options: [])
        let str = String(data: jsonData, encoding: String.Encoding.utf8)! + "\r"
        return str
    } catch let error as NSError {
        print(error)
    }
    return ""
}()
```

The json I want is => {"A":4}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Replace

```
let getJSON: String = {
```

with

```
lazy var getJSON: String = {
```

To be able to access self properties inside that String